# Symfony - Error while saving profile with accessgroup - Doctrine_Record_UnknownPropertyException

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.1

When I try to edit a user with one or more access groups it gives a 500 internal server error.

> 500 | Internal Server Error | Doctrine_Record_UnknownPropertyException
>   Unknown record property / related component "
>
> ```
> alias : Group
> foreign : id
> local : group_id
> class : sfGuardGroup
> type : 0
> table : Object(sfGuardGroupTable)
> localTable : Object(sfGuardUserGroupTable)
> name : 
> refTable : 
> onDelete : CASCADE
> onUpdate : 
> deferred : 
> deferrable : 
> constraint : 
> equal : 
> cascade : Array
> owningSide : 
> refClassRelationAlias : 
> foreignKeyName : 
> orderBy :
> ```
>
> " on "sfGuardUserGroup"
>   stack trace
>   at ()
>   in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Record/Filter/Standard.php line 55 ...
>        */
>       public function filterGet(Doctrine_Record $record, $name)
>       {
>           throw new Doctrine_Record_UnknownPropertyException(sprintf('Unknown record property / related component "%s" on "%s"', $name, get_class($record)));
>       }
>   }
>   at Doctrine_Record_Filter_Standard->filterGet(object('sfGuardUserGroup'), ' alias : Group foreign : id local : group_id class : sfGuardGroup type : 0 table : Object(sfGuardGroupTable) localTable : Object(sfGuardUserGroupTable) name : refTable : onDelete : CASCADE onUpdate : deferred : deferrable : constraint : equal : cascade : Array owningSide : refClassRelationAlias : foreignKeyName : orderBy : ')
>   in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Record.php line 1395 ...
>   at Doctrine_Record->_get('< pre> alias : Group foreign : id local : group_id class : sfGuardGroup type : 0 table : Object(sfGuardGroupTable) localTable : Object(sfGuardUserGroupTable) name : refTable : onDelete : CASCADE onUpdate : deferred : deferrable : constraint : equal : cascade : Array owningSide : refClassRelationAlias : foreignKeyName : orderBy : ', 1)
>   in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Record.php line 1350 ...
>   at Doctrine_Record->get('< pre> alias : Group foreign : id local : group_id class : sfGuardGroup type : 0 table : Object(sfGuardGroupTable) localTable : Object(sfGuardUserGroupTable) name : refTable : onDelete : CASCADE onUpdate : deferred : deferrable : constraint : equal : cascade : Array owningSide : refClassRelationAlias : foreignKeyName : orderBy : ')
>   in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Access.php line 72 ...
>   at Doctrine_Access->__get('< pre> alias : Group foreign : id local : group_id class : sfGuardGroup type : 0 table : Object(sfGuardGroupTable) localTable : Object(sfGuardUserGroupTable) name : refTable : onDelete : CASCADE onUpdate : deferred : deferrable : constraint : equal : cascade : Array owningSide : refClassRelationAlias : foreignKeyName : orderBy : ')
>   in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Collection.php line 463 ...
>   at Doctrine_Collection->add(object('sfGuardUserGroup'))
>   in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Access.php line 131 ...

I've added the UserGroup to the sfguard shema.yml but it still giving this error.

Table on db do have the user group foreign key to table group by id.
The first edition inserts the row to the table.

If I try to use the user (login it) I get always the 403 error.

I don't know much about symfony, and don know how to solve this error.

My shema.yml is

```
sfGuardGroup:
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  columns:
    name:
      type: string(255)
      unique: true
    description: string(1000)
  relations:
    Users:
      class: sfGuardUser
      refClass: sfGuardUserGroup
      local: group_id
      foreign: id
      foreignAlias: Groups
    Permissions:
      class: sfGuardPermission
      local: permission_id
      foreign: id
      refClass: sfGuardGroupPermission
      foreignAlias: Groups

sfGuardPermission:
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  columns:
    empresa_id:
      type: integer
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
      default: 1
    name:
      type: string(255)
      unique: true
    description: string(1000)
    detalles:
      type: enum
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
      values: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5',  '6','7']
    status:
      type: integer(1)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    Empresa:
      local: empresa_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
      foreignType: many
      onDelete: CASCADE
      onUpdate: CASCADE

sfGuardGroupPermission:
  options:
    symfony:
      form:   false
      filter: false
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  columns:
    group_id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
    permission_id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
  relations:
    Group:
      class: sfGuardGroup
      local: group_id
      onDelete: CASCADE
    Permission:
      class: sfGuardPermission
      local: permission_id
      onDelete: CASCADE

sfGuardUser:
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  columns:
    first_name: string(255)
    last_name: string(255)
    identificacion: string(50)
    fecha_nacimiento: date
    direcion: string()
    telefono_principal: string(50)
    telefono_adicional: string(50)
    telefono_emergencia: string(50)
    telefono_familiar: string(50)
    sexo: integer(1)
    edo_civil: string(50)
    licencia_conducir: 
      type: string(50)
      notnull: false
    licencia_conducir_fecha: 
      type: date
      notnull: false
    nacionalidad: string(50)
    empresa_id:
      type: integer
      notnull: true
    area_id:
      type: integer
      notnull: false
    ocupacion:
      type: string(50)
      notnull: true
      default: 1
    titulo:
      type: string(50)
      notnull: true
      default: 1
    grado_instruccion:
      type: string(50)
      notnull: true
      default: 1
    ingreso:
      type: date
      notnull: true
    salida:
      type: date
      notnull: false
    email_address:
      type: string(255)
      notnull: true
      unique: true
    username:
      type: string(128)
      notnull: true
      unique: true
    algorithm:
      type: string(128)
      default: sha1
      notnull: true
    salt: string(128)
    password: string(128)
    identificacion_archivo: 
      type: string(50)
      notnull: false
    domicilio_archivo: 
      type: string(50)
      notnull: false
    foto_archivo: 
      type: string(50)
      notnull: false
    is_active:
      type: boolean
      default: 1
    is_super_admin:
      type: boolean
      default: false
    last_login:
      type: timestamp
    alerta: 
      type: string()
      notnull: false
    observacion:
      type: string()
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
      notnull: false
  indexes:
    is_active_idx:
      fields: [is_active]
  relations:
    Groups:
      class: sfGuardGroup
      local: group_id
      foreign: id
      refClass: sfGuardUserGroup
      foreignAlias: Users
    Permissions:
      class: sfGuardPermission
      local: user_id
      foreign: permission_id
      refClass: sfGuardUserPermission
      foreignAlias: Users
    Empresa:
      local: empresa_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
      onDelete: CASCADE
      onUpdate: CASCADE 
    Area:
      local: area_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
      onDelete: NULL
      onUpdate: NULL 

sfGuardUserPermission:
  options:
    symfony:
      form:   false
      filter: false
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  columns:
    user_id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
    permission_id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
  relations:
    User:
      class: sfGuardUser
      local: user_id
      onDelete: CASCADE
    Permission:
      class: sfGuardPermission
      local: permission_id
      onDelete: CASCADE

sfGuardUserGroup:
  options:
    symfony:
      form:   false
      filter: false
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  columns:
    user_id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
    group_id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
  relations:
    User:
      class: sfGuardUser
      local: user_id
      onDelete: CASCADE
    Group:
      class: sfGuardGroup
      local: group_id
      onDelete: CASCADE

sfGuardRememberKey:
  options:
    symfony:
      form:   false
      filter: false
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  columns:
    user_id: integer
    remember_key: string(32)
    ip_address: string(50)
  relations:
    User:
      class: sfGuardUser
      local: user_id
      foreignAlias: RememberKeys
      foreignType: one
      onDelete: CASCADE

sfGuardForgotPassword:
  options:
    symfony:
      form:   false
      filter: false
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  columns:
    user_id:
      type: integer
      notnull: true
    unique_key: string(255)
    expires_at:
      type: timestamp
      notnull: true
  relations:
    User:
      class: sfGuardUser
      local: user_id
      type: one
      foreignType: one
      foreignAlias: ForgotPassword
      onDelete: CASCADE
```

Can some one give his shema.yml for sfGuard?

Please help me!
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read about [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in this site. Always be specific and make your best effort before asking. In this case, you show us your error and there are 1000 of possibilities for that error. I recommend you to add some piece of code. Then we can try to fix it or give you an advice.

Comment: Question edited